# How does the base case of this sort function lead to the output?

Tags: scala, sorting

[**Sort Function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd768.png)

**Highlighted part at the end is the return of the function**

I’m confused on why this function gives List(1,2,3) instead of List(1,2,1,2,3)? Like if the base case has lst in it wouldn’t the final have multiple values added to the head of lst? I’m confused on how lst comes into play in the base case (false, lst)?

Comment: We can't cut-and-paste text from an image so please don't post images or links to images as a code reference.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code and read your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. Also, please make sure to post everything relevant to answering your question *in your question*, not on some third-party site somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a description + visual representation of what's happening. Notice how `lst` is different with each iteration.

```
1st iteration -> lst = List(1,2,3)
case h1::h2::t  [i.e. 1::2::List(3)]
h1 < h2 = true
call swapper(h2::t)

    2nd iteration -> lst = List(2,3)
    case h1::h2::t  [i.e. 2::3::Nil]
    h1 < h2 = true
    call swapper(h2::t)

        3rd iteration -> lst = List(3)
        case h::Nil  [i.e. 3::Nil]
        return (false, lst)  [i.e. (false, List(3))]

    receive (swap, rest)    [i.e. (false, List(3))]
    return (swap, h1::rest) [i.e. (false, 2::List(3))]

receive (swap, rest)    [i.e. (false, List(2,3))]
return (swap, h1::rest) [i.e. (false, 1::List(2,3))]
```